# Is there a word to describe somebody who disapproves of the overuse of buzzwords?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm thinking something like 'pedantic' but I just can't think of it.

Comment: _Peever_, or _editor_, depending on whether you trust their judgement on which words actually buzz.

Comment: And then there's _buzzkiller_ But maybe _formalist_ has the slightly arch tone you're aiming for.

Comment: .......Over-50.

Comment: .... as an over-50, this grammarian will tell you you're pushing the envelope in an epic fashion.

Answer (score 1):

How about a [vocabularian](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/vocabularian):

> *noun*
>
> a person who is particularly or overly attentive to words

or a [logophile](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/logophile):

> *noun*
>
> a person who loves words

Comment: Both good suggestions McCannF but neither really portray the abhorrence / disdain for buzzwords.

Answer (score 0):

Vocabularian is fabulous. However, if you were going to use it in this context, I would suggest framing it similarly to, "too much of a vocabularian for buzzwords." Likewise, if you're looking for a reproachful type of word going the route of "the didact was swift to correct any usage of buzzwords." The person could also be punctilious (http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/punctilious) (adj. strict or exact in the observance of the formalities or amenities of conduct or actions) and dislike the misappropriation of words into buzzwords. If you want to go the simpler route, saying "anti-buzzwords" is clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

One who disapproves of too many buzzwords is called plain-speaking, or is a plain-spoken individual.

Doubtless of what single word you find to describe him he will disapprove of it.

Answer (score 0):

***Fuddy-duddy***  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuddy-duddy) says:

> A fuddy-duddy (or fuddy duddy or fuddy-dud)[1] is a person who is
>   fussy while old-fashioned, traditionalist, conformist, or
>   conservative, sometimes almost to the point of eccentricity or
>   geekiness. It is a slang term, mildly derogatory but sometimes
>   affectionate too and can be used to describe someone with a zealous
>   focus on order.

The [Cambridge English Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/fuddy-duddy) says:

> a person who has old-fashioned ideas and opinions:
>
> They think I'm an old fuddy-duddy because I don't approve of tattoos.

Neither of the definitions mention an aversion to buzz-words, but fuddy-duddies would clearly not appreciate slang or even informal words or phrases; their speech is on the formal side of 50 years ago.